# The serverside access token vs clientside access token in Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

My users need to login using the serveside flow, but I want the to upload videos and images directly to Facebook without going through my servers.

Is it possible to use the access token obtained using the serverside flow for activities using the Facebook javascript library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, sure - it will be the same token - "server side" is just a different way of getting it. You will need to communicate that token to the client-side somehow - but that totally depends on your programming language, environment etc.

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ - scroll to the "Tokens are Portable" section for the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The **access token** has nothing to do with the JS/PHP SDK.